# Extracting a sub-string in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# programming and I want to ask a question.

How can I get the value in () and store it in another string. example:
I have string

```
s1="here there (hi)";
```

How can I get

```
s2="hi";
```

the `()` will always be at the end of the sentence (never at first or in between).

Comment: can you have un matched '(' like "this is harde(r than with (no unmatched '(' )

Answer (score 8):

```
string s1 = "abc (hi)";
string s2 = s1.Substring(s1.LastIndexOf("(") + 1, s1.LastIndexOf(")") - s1.LastIndexOf("(") - 1);
```

Comment: Mind that this will throw exceptions if the source string doesn't contain parenthesis.

Comment: This implementation throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException; the second parameter to Substring should be a length, not a character index.

Comment: @Bradley Grainger: Thank you! I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s2 = s1.Substring(s1.LastIndexOf("(") + 1, s1.LastIndexOf(")") - s1.LastIndexOf("(") - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 string e1 = "here there (hi)";
//Extraction 
 string s2 = e1.Substring(e1.IndexOf("(")+1, (e1.LastIndexOf(")") - e1.IndexOf("("))-1);
```

Comment: the all above answers are wrong they will show the word in bracket......................